# How to fix 404 not found when accessing the routes in the url. (SPA REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem regarding accessing my routes, i got confuse why it's give 404 not found when I tried to access those links. I will show guys my codes that I already made in my project.

**Error:**

> 404 Not Found

**My Root Js.**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import Header from './Includes/Header'
import Footer from './Includes/Footer'
import Index from './Index'
import Routings from './Includes/Routings'

export default class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div>
                <Header/>

                    <Index/>

                    <Routings/>

                <Footer/>
           </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

Note that I just include the Routings to my main js file. so here is my codes inside of routing

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from '../Login';

export default class Routings extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/Login" component={Login}/>
                </div>  
            </Router>

        )
    }
}
```

**Project Structure:**

[image: structure]

So when i tried to access the Login, it gives 404 not found. I hope someone could help me thanks.

Comment: pretty sure its not a frontend problem but dependent on the setup of the webserver

Comment: what do you mean for this sir @jonathanHeindl

Comment: usually webservers search for a file thats the same path as the url frontend routing requires th server to redirect failed searches to the index.html

Comment: can you give more explanation for this.

Comment: so most webservers are configured to only pass files that 100% percent match the url they are given so when you request example.com/Login the server searches for an index.html in rootFolder/Login/ or maybe a file called Login in the server (no file endings is mostly disabled though) if it doesnt find it it returns a 404  your frontend routing reuqires the server to default back to the main program (usually located in the index.html of the main folder)  if a file cant be located in the folder structure

Comment: i will update my post , i will show you the structure of my project

Comment: now there could be other reasons which are more or less likely depending on your server development environment

Comment: how are you hosting this application ?

Comment: this project is just on localhost only, so when i tried to access the login the url look like this, localhost:8000/Login but 404 not found the result

Comment: which command do you use to start your server

Comment: npm run watch && php artisan serve

Comment: can you try exmaple 3 on this site excecpt repalce the ''welcome to php' part with a file reference to your index.html oO

Comment: to get the index.html you probably want to use 'echo file_get_contents('index.html');'

Comment: btw I played around a bit here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config and I never got a 404